# How To Wpf TabItem Style HeaderTemplate Binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, tabitem

How To do Wpf TabItem Style HeaderTemplate Binding?

Code:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCtrlMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

this code is not working when binding:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}"/>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this Instead,

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabCtrlMain" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding FileName}" />
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="grid">
                                    <ContentPresenter>
                                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: The biggest problem here is that you can't use a TemplateBinding inside a DataTemplate. Other than that, it should do what was asked.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is awfully old now, but I thought I'd throw my two cents in just for the sake of completeness and historical accuracy :)

I prefer to use the ItemContainerStyle to do the same thing just because it feels a little cleaner to me because it states the purpose exactly:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding FileName}" />
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
            </Border>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Also, if the only goal is to get the FileName into the tabs then it can be much simpler:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DisplayMemberPath="FileName" />
```